# 日本語に違和感: 「オープンのままにする」の説明が「クローズする必要がある場合」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

クローズ票のレビューで、各オプションの説明で以下のように表示されます:

[image: 説明]

「オープンのままにする」に対して「クローズする必要がある」という説明は矛盾しています。

代案:

> この質問をクローズする必要がない場合

Answer (score 1):

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40287385

に反映しました。（上の案から少し変更しました）